# Oracle SQL multiple aliases to one

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new in SQL and I have to write script in Oracle SQL.
I made everything except this:

```
(SELECT sai.TXPTXT FROM ARTIKELBESCHREIBUNG_KATEGORIE ak, SVZARBKATEGORIE_INHALT sai WHERE ROWNUM=1 AND(ak.KATEGORIE=25 AND ak.KATEGORIE_INHALT=sai.TXPINH AND ak.QUAL=dna.QUAL AND FIRMA=20
    OR ak.KATEGORIE=26 AND ak.KATEGORIE_INHALT=sai.TXPINH AND ak.QUAL=dna.QUAL AND FIRMA=20)) as **Fit1,**

(SELECT sai.TXPTXT FROM ARTIKELBESCHREIBUNG_KATEGORIE ak, SVZARBKATEGORIE_INHALT sai WHERE ak.KATEGORIE=27 AND ak.KATEGORIE_INHALT=sai.TXPINH AND ak.QUAL=dna.QUAL AND FIRMA=20) as **rise,**
```

I have to create a new alias with Name **PRODUCT** which have values from Fit1,rise and 3 more values  from another alias (this alias have Name ID was created with CASE Statement).

PRODUCT=Fit1,rise,ID - this is what i need

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` operation would merge the results horizontally

```
(SELECT txptxt FROM Fit1
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM rise
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM id) as PRODUCT
```

`SELECT table.*` would merge the result vertically

```
(SELECT Fit1.*, rise.*, id.* 
FROM Fit1 
JOIN rise USING(TXPTXT)
JOIN id USING(TXPTXT)) as PRODUCT
```

Comment: Tthank you for quick Response, but for id I receive an error:

Comment: 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: This is how alias ID was created:

case when pb.TXPTXT is not null and gp.TXPTXT is not null and pg.TXPTXT is not null then
 pb.TXPTXT || ' / ' || gp.TXPTXT || ' / ' || pg.TXPTXT
 end as ID

So, PRODUCT have to have Format like:

 pb.TXPTXT || ' / ' || gp.TXPTXT || ' / ' || pg.TXPTXT || fit1 || ' /  ' || rise

Sorry if I am confused...enough experience and tired make me confused a Little bit :-)

Comment: Well `id` isn't a table then. You might create it as view: `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW id AS (SELECT CASE WHEN ... END FROM DUAL)`

Comment: Can I just insert CASE Statement from ID ?

Comment: You'll have to replace `DUAL` with actual tables you're `CASE`ing from

Comment: Thank you for your help, effort and time:-)
I have to look which table actually is active...I think TXPTXT but I'm not sure…
Anyway, thank you again:-)